# problems with formatting text in CSS popup

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have one question about formatting text in CSS popup, who generate javascript.

Let's show, this is popup with CSS :

```
.photo4 {
    display: inline-block; /* Строчно-блочный элемент */
    position: relative; /* Относительное позиционирование */
}

.photo4:hover:after {
    display: inline-block;
    content: attr(data-title-id);
    white-space:pre;
    position: absolute; /* Абсолютное позиционирование */
    left: 120%; bottom: -400%; /* Положение подсказки */
    z-index: 1; /* Отображаем подсказку поверх других элементов */
    background: #003399;
    font-family: Segoe UI; font-weight: lighter; /* Гарнитура шрифта */
    font-size: 13px; /* Размер текста подсказки */
    padding: 5px 10px; /* Поля */
    color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #333; /* Параметры рамки */
    -moz-border-radius: 5px
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
}
```

This is my javascript who generate the clock text my (i'm show only string what generate him) :

```
var clock = "UTC        :   "+daymUTC+"."+monthUTC+"."+yearUTC+" "+hoursUTC+":"+minutesUTC+":"+secondsUTC+" "+suffixUTC+"\nKiev        :   "+daym+"."+month+"."+year+" "+hours+":"+minutes+":"+seconds+" "+suffix+"\nTel Aviv   :   "+daym+"."+month+"."+year+" "+hours+":"+minutes+":"+seconds+" "+suffix+"\nMontreal :   "+daymcanada+"."+monthcanada+"."+yearcanada+" "+hourscanada+":"+minutescanada+":"+secondscanada+" "+suffixcanada+"\nMinsk      :   "+daymminsk+"."+monthminsk+"."+yearminsk+" "+hoursminsk+":"+minutesminsk+":"+secondsminsk+" "+suffixminsk+" "
```

And of course HTML :

```
<div style="width:10px; float:left; padding-top:20px;" >
<div class="photo4" ><img src="{{ STATIC_URL }}images/time.png" width="22" height="22px"></div>
</div></div>
```

And screen with result :
http://www.ex.ua/289430303487

And so the question that I need to do to for example ":" standing in line, and a uniform space uniformly stood clock (by the way it changes every second)

Comment: use a monospace font and format the time to always have leading zeros

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the data to stick without moving when the time changes

Make a table within the popup so data will be evenly spaced

As for 9:16:04 etc make it 09:16:04 so there will be no change when it hits 10:00:00

If this is not what your asking, could you be a bit more clearer? Cheers